# Python getattr equivalent for dictionaries?

Tags: python

What's the most succinct way of saying, in Python, "Give me `dict['foo']` if it exists, and if not, give me this other value `bar`"? If I were using an object rather than a dictionary, I'd use `getattr`:

```
getattr(obj, 'foo', bar)
```

but this raises a key error if I try using a dictionary instead (a distinction I find unfortunate coming from JavaScript/CoffeeScript). Likewise, in JavaScript/CoffeeScript I'd just write

```
dict['foo'] || bar
```

but, again, this yields a KeyError. What to do? Something *succinct*, please!

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`dict.get(key, default)` returns `dict[key]` if key in dict, else returns default.

Note that the default for `default` is `None` so if you say `dict.get(key)` and key is not in dict then this will just return `None` rather than raising a `KeyError` as happens when you use the `[]` key access notation.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for! I think you just set a new speed record.

Comment: Hey is it possible to do this only for a particular characteristic of key... [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6467555/5961780), a value is only returned when 'key', or rather 'name', starts with the letter 'f'.

Answer (score 6):

Also take a look at collections module's defaultdict class. It's a dict for which you can specify what it must return when the key is not found. With it you can do things like:

```
class MyDefaultObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(MyDefaultObj)
i = d['NonExistentKey']
type(i)
<instance of class MyDefalutObj>
```

which allows you to use the familiar d[i] convention.

However, as mikej said, .get() also works, but here is the form closer to your JavaScript example:

```
d = {}
i = d.get('NonExistentKey') or MyDefaultObj()
# the reason this is slightly better than d.get('NonExistent', MyDefaultObj())
# is that instantiation of default value happens only when 'NonExistent' does not exist.
# With d.get('NonExistent', MyDefaultObj()) you spin up a default every time you .get()
type(i)
<instance of class MyDefalutObj>
```